# React Router useParams hook returning empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with React Router not getting params using the `useParams` hook. When going to the route `/view/12345` (browser path includes basename `/pending-nominations/view/12345`) the `console.log()` logs an empty object here `{}` where it should be displaying the `id` eg. `{id: 12345}`

```
const SingleRecognition = (props) => {
    let params = useParams();
    console.log("SingleRecognition -> params", params)

    return (
        <div>
            id: 
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Router basename="/pending-nominations">
                <PageNav/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/history">
                        <History/>
                    </Route>
                    <Router path="/view/:id">
                        <SingleRecognition/>
                    </Router>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <PendingRecognitions/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Looking at the example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams this should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have problem because you used `Router` instead of `Route`.

Comment:  too much time at the computer. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean Router instead of Route? I ran into the same issue

Comment: React router has to components `Router` and `Route`. So you can easy make mistake to use `Router` instead `Route`.